# Header not full width - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

My header of my webpage is a image. The only problem is that it is not the full width of the page it stretches to the end of the right side of the page but not the left. **My question is how do I make it fit the whole page width?** I have done some searching and haven't found anything. I have tried changing all the css elements with no luck.  Not sure why this is happening.

Here is the css:

```
header{
   position: absoulute;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   background: url(images/logo2.png) no-repeat;
   height:100px;
   left: 0px;
   margin-left: 0;   
}
```

the html:

```
<img src="Images/logo2.png" width="1459" height="372" /></a>
<div id="header"></a></div>
```

So let me summarize my question one more time. I want the header image to be full width of the screen.

you can see the whole page 
[here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10329732/csc110/index2.html).

Comment: End `</a>`, but not start `</a>` ?

Comment: Who creates websites like this these days? :)) The demo link does not look like the code you are sharing here.

Comment: try to validate your code as it goes: http://validator.w3.org

Comment: @AdrianFlorescu what do you mean "creates websites like this these days"? and the source is the same.

Comment: and i start my formating with dreamweaver but type the rest my self so you can thank adobe for the format

Comment: @apples dreamweaver should be only to facilitate the work, you must validate your code for the link that you spent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is simply fix your ID selector. IDs are selected by prepending a hash character before it. In your case, the code would be:

```
#header{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   background: url(images/logo2.png) no-repeat;
   height:100px;
   left: 0px;
   margin-left: 0;   
}
```

Notice the `#` before `header`. I've also corrected your `position: absoulute` to `position: absolute`.

Comment: no matter what i do doesnt fit the whole page edge to edge you can see  on the link above in the question i have changed to what you suggested still nothing

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but i just made a simple rectangle with my gradient and put it in place of the missing space

Comment: It works for me but eats a bit of the content underneath it. Any ideea why?

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu It's been a long time since this post, but it looks like I just took the asker's code and applied some general fixes (he misspelled `absolute` and he was missing a `#` in his ID selector). It seems like the asker has figured it out though, so you could try asking him. Or you could check out the other answers below.

Answer (score 6):

Set 0px margin and padding for body.

CSS:

```
body{    
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

I hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

## View Here.

#### http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/j5BNC/

Your best bet is to make your **#header image 2200px+ and reduce**, otherwise it'll pixelate.

#### Edit:

> **@apples**. Any sort of **templating system** (dev tools like **dreamweaver** or **frontpage**) is pretty dangerous. It applies all sorts of styles and whatnot and makes your page pretty dirty and not
> cross compatible. Even if it works, it may not on other browsers,
> resolutions, etc.

[image]

```
#header {
    position:relative;
}

#header img {
    position:absolute;
    max-width:100%;
}
```